# how to optimise the case statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

the below query case contains an index but not using it. then one column is a mediumtext how to optimize that column and I think the query needs to improve the search efficiency by rewriting.  please find the structure of the table and the query below.

```
select 
  `up`.`id` AS `post_id`, 
  `c`.`id` AS `community_id`, 
  substr(`up`.`description`, 1, 30) AS `post_description`, 
  `c`.`name` AS `community_name`, 
  `c`.`is_index` AS `is_index`, 
  `c`.`slug` AS `slug`, 
  `p`.`last_modified_on` AS `last_modified_on`, 
  `c`.`is_shop` AS `is_shop` 
from 
  `user_post` `up`  
  join `community` `c` 
  join `participant` `pa` 
  join `participating_entity` `p` 
  left join `indexed_post` `ip` on(
    (
      (
        `ip`.`user_post_id` = `up`.`id`
      ) 
      and (`ip`.`is_active` = 1)
    )
  ) 
where 
  (
    (`p`.`is_active` = 1) 
    and (`up`.`is_spam_post` = 0) 
    and (
      `p`.`id` = `up`.`participating_entity_id`
    ) 
    and isnull(`ip`.`id`) 
    and length(`up`.`description` >= 20) 
    and (
      `pa`.`id` = (
        case when (`pa`.`is_active` = 1) then `c`.`participant_id` end
      )
    ) 
    and (
      `c`.`id` = (
        case when (`c`.`is_index` = 1) then `up`.`community_id` end
      )
    )
  ) 
order by 
  `up`.`id` 
limit 
  358223, 
  5000\G
```

explain plan;

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10895
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pa
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: idx_is_active
      key_len: 2
          ref: NULL
         rows: 14728254
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: up
   partitions: NULL
         type: range
possible_keys: fk_user_post_entity1_idx,is_spam_post,idx_is_spam_post,idx_test1,idx_combo,idx_testing
          key: is_spam_post
      key_len: 2
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1238100
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: ip
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_user_post_id,idx_aaa
          key: idx_user_post_id
      key_len: 8
          ref: she.up.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where; Not exists
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: p
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_aaa
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: she.up.participating_entity_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using where
```

```
               (or)
```

Query model 2:

```
SELECT 
  up.id post_id, 
  c.id community_id, 
  SUBSTRING(up.description, 1, 30) post_description, 
  c.name community_name, 
  c.is_index is_index, 
  c.slug slug, 
  p.last_modified_on last_modified_on, 
  c.is_shop is_shop 
FROM 
  user_post up 
  INNER JOIN community c force index(fk_community_participant1_idx) ON up.community_id = c.id 
  and c.is_index = 1 
  inner join participant pa on c.participant_id = pa.id 
  and pa.is_active = 1 
  inner join participating_entity p on up.participating_entity_id = p.id 
  left join indexed_post ip on ip.user_post_id = up.id 
  and ip.is_active = 1 
WHERE 
  p.is_active = 1 
  and up.is_spam_post = 0 
  and ip.id is null 
  and LENGTH(up.description) >= 20 
order by 
  up.id 
limit 
  188223, 
  5000;
```

explain plan ;

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: fk_community_participant1_idx
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10895
     filtered: 33.33
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pa
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_is_active
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: she.c.participant_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: up
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: fk_user_post_community1_idx,fk_user_post_entity1_idx,is_spam_post,idx_is_spam_post,idx_community_id_participating_entity_id_is_spam_post,idx_test1,idx_community_recipient_id,idx_combo,idx_test,idx_testing,idx_testing1
          key: idx_community_id_participating_entity_id_is_spam_post
      key_len: 9
          ref: she.c.id
         rows: 340
     filtered: 25.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: ip
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_user_post_id,idx_aaa
          key: idx_user_post_id
      key_len: 8
          ref: she.up.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where; Not exists
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: p
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_aaa
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: she.up.participating_entity_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using where
```

Table structure;

```
Table : Community c

the mediumtext column contains in this table.
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: community
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `community` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `participant_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `community_type_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `**description` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,**
  `logo_url` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cover_image_url` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_closed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `parent_participant_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'id of users for mentor\nid of company_profile for company community',
  `purpose` varchar(4000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_featured` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `featured_start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `featured_end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `cover_height` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cover_width` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cover_ratio` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `logo_height` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `logo_width` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `logo_ratio` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `primary_color` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondary_color` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_tab_joined_key` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'feed',
  `default_tab_key` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'about',
  `new_post_hint` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `title_text_color` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `onboarding_community_priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `short_branch_url` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `score_latest` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `logo_alt_text` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cover_alt_text` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_community_members` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `supported_languages` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_index` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `location_master_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_shop` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_community_participant1_idx` (`participant_id`),
  KEY `fk_community_community_type1_idx` (`community_type_id`),
  KEY `idx_parent_participant_id` (`parent_participant_id`),
  KEY `idx_score_latest` (`score_latest`),
  KEY `slug` (`slug`(191)),
  KEY `idx_participant_is_index` (`participant_id`,`is_index`),
  KEY `idx_is_index_participant` (`is_index`,`participant_id`),
  KEY `idx_participant_id_is_index` (`participant_id`,`is_index`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_community_community_type1` FOREIGN KEY (`community_type_id`) REFERENCES `community_type` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_community_participant1` FOREIGN KEY (`participant_id`) REFERENCES `participant` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12831 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci


Table : participant pa

*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: participant
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `participant` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `participant_type_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `crdt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `is_deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `partner_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sheroes_deep_link` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_participant_participation_type1_idx` (`participant_type_id`),
  KEY `idx_participant_last_modified_on` (`last_modified_on`),
  KEY `idx_participant_crdt` (`crdt`),
  KEY `sheroes_deep_link` (`sheroes_deep_link`(191)),
  KEY `idx_is_active` (`is_active`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_participant_participation_type1` FOREIGN KEY (`participant_type_id`) REFERENCES `participant_type` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15123249 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci


Table : participating_entity p

*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: participating_entity
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `participating_entity` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entity_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `crdt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `title` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `shared_with` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'sister hood, public or community',
  `is_deactivated` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `partner_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sheroes_deep_link` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` enum('en','hi','te','ta','mr','gu','pa','ja','bh','as','bn','ur','ml','kn','zh','es','ar','pt','ru','de','jv','ko','vi','fr','it','tr','fa','pl','uk','or','my','th','id','ms','sv','nl') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'en',
  `is_campaign_content` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_entity_entity_type_idx` (`entity_type_id`),
  KEY `idx_participating_entity_last_modified_on` (`last_modified_on`),
  KEY `created_by` (`created_by`),
  KEY `fk_partner_id_idx` (`partner_id`),
  KEY `crdt` (`crdt`),
  KEY `idx_category` (`category`),
  KEY `idx_created_by` (`created_by`),
  KEY `idx_aaa` (`is_active`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_entity_entity_type` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `entity_type` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_partner_id` FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `api_consumer_partner` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4180158 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci


Table:  indexed_post ip

*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: indexed_post
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `indexed_post` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_post_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `crdt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_user_post_id` (`user_post_id`),
  KEY `idx_aaa` (`user_post_id`,`is_active`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1942 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Table : user_post up

*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: user_post
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `user_post` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `participating_entity_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `is_public` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `users_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `community_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_community_post` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_anonymous` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `og_image_url` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `og_title` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `og_description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `og_requested_url` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_og_video_link` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_title` varchar(190) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_description` varchar(190) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_entity_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_type` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `entity_start_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_comment_allowed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `is_spam_post` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `hash_tag` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_top_post` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `top_post_marked_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `approved_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `disapproved_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `short_branch_url` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `partner_branch_url` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_posted_on_facebook` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `likes_count` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `comments_count` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `engagement_score` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `has_mentions` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `mentions` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `theme_text_color` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `theme_image_url` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `recipient_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `repost_count` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_theme_post` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `theme_text_font_size` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `descriptions1` bigint(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (length(`description`)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_user_post_users1_idx` (`users_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_post_community1_idx` (`community_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_post_entity1_idx` (`participating_entity_id`),
  KEY `idx_source_ent_id` (`source_entity_id`),
  KEY `idx_entity_start_dt` (`entity_start_date`),
  KEY `idx_rating_for_company` (`rating`),
  KEY `user_post_source_type` (`source_type`),
  KEY `is_spam_post` (`is_spam_post`),
  KEY `idx_is_spam_post` (`is_spam_post`),
  KEY `idx_is_theme_post` (`is_theme_post`),
  KEY `idx_meta_title` (`meta_title`),
  KEY `idx_meta_description` (`meta_description`),
  KEY `idx_recipient_id` (`recipient_id`),
  KEY `idx_title` (`title`(191)),
  KEY `idx_community_id_participating_entity_id_is_spam_post` (`community_id`,`participating_entity_id`,`is_spam_post`),
  KEY `idx_combo` (`participating_entity_id`,`community_id`,`is_spam_post`),
  KEY `idx_test` (`descriptions1`),
  KEY `idx_testing` (`is_spam_post`,`descriptions1`),
  KEY `idx_testing1` (`descriptions1`,`is_spam_post`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_post_community1` FOREIGN KEY (`community_id`) REFERENCES `community` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_post_entity1` FOREIGN KEY (`participating_entity_id`) REFERENCES `participating_entity` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_post_users1` FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3175041 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

does this have any possible optimization for the above  ?

Comment: your query looks wrong, i would expect an ON clause after very joined table , so that a link will be established

Comment: no not really for that i must build your from clause  completely new, and i can't make senseor rime of your schema, but as you enetered the data, you must "see" the links between the tables and know which columns are the referenece

Comment: Hi, @nbk can you please explain where did I make the mistakes?

Comment: i have 2 query can you please suggest which one is better?

Comment: @nbk please find the details above.

Comment: when you link two tables lets say a and b You write `FROM A JOIN B ON A.ID = b.A_ID`so in my case i know right from the start A and B are linked and i know both sides of the relationship. and that you have to make for all tables you got

Comment: ok ok, can you please tell me which one is better if anything is better than both means can you please rewrite this one as an answer?

Comment: there is no better, to help you we need to understand your design and model. that is why i told you to start by yourself as there are only  tables, you will be quick

Comment: This is an application-side query the only thing I have in my hand is the o/p data for the above query. can I post that output?@nbk

Comment: Please don't cross-post.  I already discussed why `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` are the villains.

Comment: hi @Rick James is there any other way? cuz the query perform in the prod server.

Comment: that's why i cross-post again